# barely any upvotes compared to other SEs

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

On many other stack exchanges points are easy to come by.  Scrolling down the first few pages of questions on this one, however, shows an extremely small amount of 'up-votes'.  Why is this?  How can it change?  Questions, answers, comments that one feels are helpful in any matter should get the 'thumbs-up'.

Comment: Fully agree and excellent question. There are a lot of high ranking people here that simply do not up vote good questions. No problem leaving answers though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Firstly thank you for you post. This is something that is really highlighted by looking at the voting stats on the site on a user level. My thinking is that people see this site as a competition and not a community effort. I can help you on how to start to change this and it starts with individuals like yourself (and like everyone other user on this site).

It is plain and simple while you are using the site if you see an answer/question that you like up vote it. If you see an answer/question you do not like then down vote it. If you can get into this habit, also maybe spend 5 mins going through all questions on one page of a tag you are most comfortable in then you on your own can start to make a change on this site.

If we can get our regular users to to this it will help the site grow and hopefully switch people's mind set from that of a competition to that of a community who support each other.

Thank you so much for using this website.

Comment: agree...this community can be much more than just competition....let us help each other in good faith....

Comment: Totally agree we need more voting, my conclusion in [this](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/469/can-we-increase-answer-acceptance-rate) question was that while you can't do much about those that ask questions not accepting answers, we can all up/down vote hugely more than we do.  I think it's a really important aspect of the site, but yes, less competition, more liberal use of votes has to be the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Lets see, we currently have 300-400 upvotes per month, that number is somehow stable and its to await it will be the same for the current month.

http://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/219032/number-of-votes-per-month#graph

Lets compare this with your strongest SE (Travel)
There are between 1000 and 2000 upvotes per month, so yes, a lot more.

http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/219032/number-of-votes-per-month#resultSets

how do the beta stats compare:

Travel did launch over a year ago, it had bit of a better answer ratio, and 100% answered questions(great!) we are still in beta, mostly because we only have a answer rate of 71% as we already have a lot more users, views and questions per day.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel

but, how does it compares today:

Magento:

```
17k questions 
20k answers 
71% answered 
13k users 
20k visits/day 
50 questions/day 
2y site age
```

Travel:

```
9.9k questions 
18k answers 
99% answered 
16k users 
21k visits/day 
13 questions/day 
3y7m site age
```

So to answer your Question, I think its because on other SEs you already have on the first page questions which are a few Days old.
Also our Questions usually need a serious effort to answer, and we have a lot of questions with not so great quality.

But yeah, we also have a lot of users who dont actively go trough questions and spreading votes, maybe we have to many drive by users, who never come back?
That would need a few more data querys to analyze

Comment: Magento SE has 2 years already ?! gosh

Answer (score 8):

I usually would only upvote answers which I think have a high probability of being a correct answer / valid approach to the questions asked. Due to the nature of Magento for a lot of answers on topics that I haven't encountered before I would need to recreate the issue and then test the code to confirm it is working.

This is an effort I'd rather spend answering questions which don't have an answer yet. If you look at what type of questions do get lots of votes on our site https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes you will find quite a few questions which don't require specific code knowledge and are borderline opinion based. These answers are easier to validate and in my opinion easier to upvote.

Comment: I agree it is hard to cast votes sometimes. Most of the questions are related to extending core functionality rather than questions about existing core functionality. This makes it hard to answer/cast votes as without doing very specific testing of the scenario described in the question, or answer given. I rarely have time to do this around regular work but without it, it's not practically possible to ascertain whether a vote is warranted or not. I do think this is a fairly significant aspect holding back voting, and has no easy solution as people should be able to ask any question.

Comment: One should upvote questions too.  Novelty, difficulty, usefulness, etc.

Comment: Agreed that we could do a better job in upvoting good questions.

Answer (score 6):

One of the issues with the lack of upvotes is that it makes it very difficult for some newer users of the Magento SE to gain good reputation points. I have been very hesitant to answer questions or interact on Magento SE because I cannot comment on a question if further information is needed. All of my 11 years and 50+ magento implementations and interactions with other users has been on the Magento Community forum.

It also appears that people are very quick to close questions down because of lack of info provided in the question even though the question is valid and does not need further information. It would be better to offer a button that is something like, Question needs more info. If more than 3 users vote that, then the question should be on hold.

If you take look at some of the Facebook groups about Magento, you'll find that they are extremely disappointed in the Magento SE.. It's up to SE to get this thing rolling, and would love to see it!

Comment: Could you list some of this facebook groups?

Answer (score 5):

Aren't there badges that stimulate upvoting ? There is even a golden one.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I would end up on Magento SE through Google. I have a problem myself and I try to find the answer by Google'ing. If I find a good question and/or answer then I would definitely up-vote it.

The questions and answers I find here are of very low quality that don't meet our company's standards.

A lot of questions concern people searching for extensions, basic Magento stuff of which you could find the answer on Magento sites/docs, etc...

Like I said, answers (code) don't meet our company's standards, for example changing core Magento code as a solution and other non upgrade safe solutions.

I would encourage people to up-vote the qualitatively good questions/answers and to down-vote or flag poor ones. It would always help people to indicate what is good/bad about a question or answer!

Comment: Where you have an open forum like SE you are always going to have both good and bad answers as there will be developers on here with varying levels of experience. I can't however actually remember the last time I saw an answer suggesting poor development practices - it's certainly not at all regular as it seems you are suggesting. While I'm sure there are answers like this I think you'll find these kinds of answers are quickly downvoted. It's our job to be active in up/down voting questions and answers to moderate and improve the quality of content on the site.