# Upvoting the question when answering

Tags: discussion, voting

If I look at the pages with newest questions, then I see a lot of good questions with good answers, but all the questions have score 0.
Isn't it logical that when you think a question qualifies for a nice answer from you, that the question therefor is good and needs an upvote? If the question is worth answering, then the question itself is good.

What I'm trying to say here, can't we all upvote the question when providing a (serious) answer?

Like already mentioned [here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99/lets-promote-a-healthy-ier-beta):

> we can encourage faster growth:
>
> - [...]
> - **More *question* upvotes** - do your part to upvote interesting questions.

And in an answer from JoeyH to ["barely any upvotes ..."](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/476/barely-any-upvotes-compared-to-other-ses/492#492):

> One of the issues with the lack of upvotes is that it makes it very difficult for some newer users of the Magento SE to gain good reputation points.

I think that if the OP's get rewarded with an upvote that this will stimulate return visits (instead of all those one time visits).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are somehow right. This website seams to not have a big voting culture yet.
But I want to challenge

> you think a question qualifies for a nice answer from you, that the question therefor is good and needs an upvote.

I answered a lot of crappy questions for which the OP could have found an answer with a simple search over the web (I think there is a tool that lets you search the web).
For sure I'm not going to upvote that kind of question (I've even downvoted some of them).

But what you say sounds good. We should all vote on questions, vote on answers (up or down).

Comment: I want to make "mariusing" a term like "googling"

Comment: @benmarks. "I have an issue and I've been mariusing for the last 2 hours and still no solution"....sounds awful.  Let's not do that.

Comment: No no no. The proper usage is, "I just mariused the heck out of 10 questions on Stack Exchange!"

Comment: @benmarks. Ah. Sorry for my bad fake English. But it still sounds bad.

Comment: *For sure I'm not going to upvote that kind of question (I've even downvoted some of them).* Seriosly or sarcasm?

Comment: @sv3n. Seriously.

Comment: IMHO it would be better to answer, but still downvote them. However you're right with *We should all vote on questions, vote on answers (up or down).*

Answer (score 1):

> I think that if the OP's get rewarded with an upvote that this will stimulate return visits (instead of all those one time visits).

Why not *"**Down**voting the question when answering"*, too?

I'd like to see less questions with one-line descriptions. Questions with absolutly no reseach effort.

Why not keep (or improve) quality with encouraging others to write better questions? Why not downvoting bad (in quality) answers?

Comment: Hi Sv3n, the question is almost a year old and I indeed too see lots of one line questions lately. I do think we do not downvote enough, at least I do when looking at my up/down vote ratio and the amount of poor questions. I do think if questions are really poor, closing is better than downvote alone because closing can also make the question get removed.

Comment: @7ochem thats what Im doing ... close and down. I can be wrong, but it seems the quantity increased, but the quality of questions has dropped. My account is ~1y old, but I heavily use SE since I started with magento ~8y ago. For years I had no need to ask my own questions. Just using google, search or "marius" but today it easier to ask. IMHO its not so good for the quality of this board :(